# How to import Highmaps map collection in Angular 6

Tags: angular, highcharts

I'm trying to use Highmaps in Angular. I declare Highmap like so:

```js
    import * as Highmaps from 'highcharts/highmaps';
```

This seems to work well as it displays an empty box with a title, missing the map itself.

So I also installed the map collection as described [here](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/map-collection).

```
    npm i @highcharts/map-collection
```

But how to import the map collection in Angular?

The tutorial describes how to import the maps in node.js:

```js
    var Highcharts = require('highcharts/highmaps.js'),
    map = require('@highcharts/map-collection/custom/world.geo.json');
```

What is the equivalent in Angular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow the instructions on this github page 
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular

I think this is the correct version you are looking for. The other one is the plain JS version

You can find the map loading example in this link.
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular/blob/master/src/app/app.component.ts

Please take a look

```js
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import MapModule from 'highcharts/modules/map';
const mapWorld = require('@highcharts/map-collection/custom/world.geo.json')
MapModule(Highcharts);
```

Comment: Yes, I followed that, but it doesn't say how to load the maps, only how to declare Highmaps. I tried `import * as MapCollection from '@highcharts/map-collection';` but  it's not working. How to import the map collections in Angular?

Comment: @ps0604, I have updated the answer with the example link

Answer (score 2):

You need to import **`MapChart`** from highcharts first,

```
import { Chart, MapChart } from 'angular-highcharts';
```

and then,

```
const Highcharts = {maps: {}};
require('../assets/maps')(Highcharts);
```

check out the **[Demo](https://github.com/sajeetharan/angular5-highmaps)**